# Debian server unable to connect to network

Tags: networking, debian, linux-networking

My server is unable to connect to the local network or Internet.

The server cannot ping other machines on the local network. Attempts to reach the Internet fail.

From my PC I can ping local IP 192.168.2.1 and 8.8.8.8.

I can connect to my server using ssh with the 192.168.2.23 IP address.

`ip addr show`

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s31f6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 6c:4b:90:a3:dc:d0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.2.23/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global dynamic enp0s31f6
       valid_lft 257944sec preferred_lft 257944sec
    inet6 fe80::6e4b:90ff:fea3:dcd0/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 98:2c:bc:e3:50:f8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: br-8c5379765694: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 02:42:0c:8e:60:31 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.24.0.1/16 brd 172.24.255.255 scope global br-8c5379765694
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: br-44cc32b7ce2f: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 02:42:5d:a8:01:63 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.19.0.1/16 brd 172.19.255.255 scope global br-44cc32b7ce2f
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:5dff:fea8:163/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 02:42:18:1f:a5:14 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: br-5e82d16c5e19: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 02:42:54:02:25:66 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.23.0.1/16 brd 172.23.255.255 scope global br-5e82d16c5e19
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
79: veth64b6284@if78: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-44cc32b7ce2f state UP group default
    link/ether e6:ca:08:af:bc:c9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet6 fe80::e4ca:8ff:feaf:bcc9/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

`Trace route`

```
    traceroute to 192.168.2.1 (192.168.2.1), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.2.23 (192.168.2.23)  741.652 ms !H  741.585 ms !H  741.546 ms !H
```

`route n`

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.2.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp0s31f6
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.19.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-44cc32b7ce2f
172.23.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-5e82d16c5e19
172.24.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-8c5379765694
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp0s31f6
```

`iptables -L`

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain DOCKER (4 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.19.0.2           tcp dpt:9091

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (4 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

I appreciate suggestions to resolve this networking issue.

**edit:**

```
wget 8.8.8.8
--2024-03-08 19:52:58--  http://8.8.8.8/
Connecting to 8.8.8.8:80... failed: No route to host.
wget google.com
--2024-03-08 19:53:23--  http://google.com/
Resolving google.com (google.com)... failed: Temporary failure in name resolution.
cat /etc/resolv.conf
domain home
search home
nameserver 192.168.2.1
```

Comment: How do you attempt to reach the internet? What fails? What error messages do you get?

Comment: @vidarlo wget§ping on hostname cannot resolve. And wget on ip address failed: no route to host.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include exact commands and errors? And also include content of `/etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: @vidarlo done thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so it's really strange after spending over 4 hours on the problem.

I activated my WiFi card and there was the opposite issue: I could see everyone, but no one within the network could see me. Then after a few minutes, I lost connection again. I retested with my Ethernet card and encountered the same problem: unable to contact the outside, but from the inside, other machines could see me.

I thought it was probably a problem with my ISP Bell GigaHub router since everything worked before it asked me to factory reset. So I deleted the DHCP leases, and my WiFi connection got a new IP and worked perfectly. So, I thought, okay, easy, I reconnect my Ethernet card and it gets the IP again as 2.23 and the same problem arises.

So, from the router, I force it to 2.123 and everything works again. It's more or less similar symptoms to an IP conflict, except I'm 100% sure there were no conflicts. Anyway, the IP 2.23 is banned on my network and I don't know why.